# Split cat() output into new lines with bullet points on rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating an Rmarkdown report and I did like to list some items with bullet points, I have items inside **cat** function like this:

```
cat(
  "First Case Reported in : ","•",as.character(as.Date("2023-01-23")),
  "TB outbreak been ongoing for"," •",paste0(55,' ', 'Weeks'),
  "cummulative cases"," •",4567," ",
  "Total cases in last 24hrs"," •", 67)
)
```

I want to split this into separate lines  for easy visibility

I have tried `sep="\n"` but its giving wrong output:

```
cat(
  "First Case Reported in : ","•",as.character(as.Date("2023-01-23")),
  "TB outbreak been ongoing for"," •",paste0(55,' ', 'Weeks'),
  "cummulative cases"," •",4567," ",
  "Total cases in last 24hrs"," •", 67, sep="\n"
)
```

**my Desired output**

```
First Case Reported in :  • 2023-01-23 
TB outbreak been ongoing for  • 55 Weeks 
cummulative cases  • 4567   
Total cases in last 24hrs  • 67
```

What is the clever way of nailing this on rmarkdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be `cat()`, you can manually place those newlines (and remove separator as the default value, `" "`, messes with output alignment) :

````
```{r}
cat(
  "First Case Reported in : • ",as.character(as.Date("2023-01-23")),"\n",
  "TB outbreak been ongoing for • ",paste0(55,' ', 'Weeks'),"\n",
  "cummulative cases • ",4567," \n",
  "Total cases in last 24hrs • ", 67, "\n", sep = ""
)
```
````

Though your kintted output will look like this:
[image]

So why not inline code in your Markdown?

````
```{r include=FALSE}
obreak    <- 55
cases_c   <- 4567
cases_24h <- 67
```
````

```markdown
First Case Reported in : • `r as.character(as.Date("2023-01-23"))`  
TB outbreak been ongoing for • `r obreak` Weeks  
cummulative cases • `r cases_c`  
Total cases in last 24hrs • `r cases_24h`
```

Same on a screenshot to emphasize blocks and 2 spaces at the end of Markdown lines to introduce linebreaks in Markdown:
[image]

Resulting knit:
[image]